# Update only one column value in Access Database - VB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, sql-update, tableadapter

I have a feature in my application where a user can opt to UNsubscribe itself. When this happens, there is no change made to the other fields in database and only user's Subscription flag is unchecked. I am doing this by getting a datarow and settingone of the field values and then updating the datarow in the table.

This is working fine for all of the recently created records, however some of the old records have a blank value set for a date field which is now mandatory. Hence when I try to unsubscribe old record of this type, it tries to retrieve null value from the database and then update the same back resulting in an error - "Cannot insert null value in Date Field"

Comment: can u please update the question with code?

Comment: Either modify your update code to handle nulls, or run a query to set all null dates to some 'old' date... i.e. 4/28/1949

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you have a table with a null value in a mandatory column, you would be better served to run an update query on the table that will enter a default value for this mandatory/required column.  Wayne G. Dunn mentioned this in the comments to your question.  For example:

```
UPDATE [TABLE1] SET [datefield] = '4/28/1949' where [datefield] = null
```

> **Be sure to backup your data prior to running this kind of query and test with a test table before you execute the query on production data.

Second, if you are doing an update to a row and setting the checkbox value to true, you can review any columns that are required and set their default value in the update query. This makes the query more complex and more difficult to support.

I advise you go with the first option and run an update query on the table.  The second option adds unnecessary code to your query that updates the checkbox.

*If you post some query examples and table structure, you will get more specific answers.  You may consider editing your question to include these details.*